# Accidentally visiting a FIFO

Tags: dired, files

I'm in Dired, and one of the files in the current directory is a named pipe (FIFO)

```
prw-r--r--+   1 ivan staff          0 Feb  6 11:13 some_pipe
```

If I (accidentally) visit it (with *dired-visit-file*), Emacs appears to freeze. This is not all that surprising, but I'm not sure what it's doing. I can break out of the frozen state by hammering on `C-M-c` (*exit-recursive-edit*) and `C-g` (*keyboard-quit*), though even that behaves inconsistently (sometimes it works after about 3 taps, sometimes it requires more, and a mix of both commands).

What I'd most like to know is what the expected behavior *should* be when a user tries to visit a FIFO, and maybe more importantly, how to prevent such accidental visitations.

Comment: Good question. Wrt the hanging, please consider filing an Emacs bug, assuming you see this also when starting Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file): `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Drew If I open the fifo with `emacs -Q`, I can hit `C-g` and the editor is available as normal. Must be something in my config. I'll investigate. I think I  might try to add a confirmation prompt if the file we're attempting to visit is a fifo.

Comment: Recursively bisect your init file, by commenting out a region of text (`M-x comment-region`): first 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16...

Comment: Emacs is trying to read from the fifo, which blocks unless someone also writes to it. Then it reports `File exists, but cannot be read`, at least for me. Not sure why the latter is the case.